# display specific error message on coupon code instead of coupon not valid

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes, error-message

how it is possible to get the reason that a coupon code is invalid? For example, if I have a shopping cart rule that specifies that the order subtotal must be Rs1000 or more, and the user tries to use the coupon on a subtotal that is only Rs750, could I show a message along the lines of "your cart must be Rs1000 or more"?

Comment: Please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29405

Comment: I have my api which throws coupon not valid when coupon does not apply.I just want to do change in the error message so that it prints the reason that why coupon is invalid.